How can I return the result of the insert query into C# variable (PostgreSQL)?
My Oracle code:
insert into table_2 (id, id_parent, id_type, name, alias, id_filewav, GUID)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning rowid into ?

I have to rewrite this to make it work with PostgreSQL. Initially the end of the query was like
returning rowid into ?

And with this command took my C# variable as a parameter. But PostgreSQL doesn't have into in its returning construction. How can I make PostgreSQL work the same way?
I tried to use returning but I can't connect it with variable.

Can you show us a complete query (minimized),

Where does your query come from?

insert into table_2 (id, id_parent, id_type, name, alias, id_filewav, GUID)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) returning rowid into ? — Oracle

You SQL query needs to looks something like this
PRINCIPAL_INSERT = $"insert into mytable (Id, Email, .....) values(@Id, @Email, .....) RETURNING Id";

So you just specify the name of the column that you are returning from the query.
Then you code can look like this
            var id = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync(PRINCIPAL_INSERT, entity);

